# Is there a way to get the i(i changes) lsb from an int?

Tags: java, lsb

I'm working on a project in java recently and i would like to handle the bits of an integer so that i can check the i lsb of a number.
I have found a lot of approaches but nothing that can handle properly...

**Example**

key= `4`
Key `4` in binary is `100`
I would like in some way to extract the 3rd LSB of `4` which is `1`.
Is there an algorithm that can do that?

Comment: Do you know binary arithmetic? Use that. Also, upto what integer value does `key` go?

Comment: @Hanut positive values

Comment: [Java Tutorial: Bitwise and Bit Shift Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)

Comment: I meant the range 0 to +inf?

Comment: @Hanut I dont think the range is much problem in my project...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using bit-shifting and bitwise AND: (indexed from 0)

```
int getBit(int number, int index)
{
  return (number >> index) & 1;
}
```

`getBit(4, 2)` returns 1.

You can also use `% 2` instead of `& 1`.

Comment: Excellent and elegant approach!!! Thank you very much! Maybe that will be the ONE

Answer (score 2):

Make a bitmask and shift:

```
int bitmask = 4;

int extractedBit = (i & BIT3) >> 2; // is now the 3rd lsb.
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, try this. Since the 3rd LSB would be based on the value of the units place of the number no mater however large it be, the value would be 0 if it was either less than four or greater than 7. So `(0,1,2,3)U(8,9)` in the units place give 3rd LSB as `0`. `(4,5,6,7)` give `1`.

```
int key = 12000;
int i=4;
if((key/(10^(i-1))%10 < 4 || (key/(10^(i-1))%10 >7)
    lsb3 = 0;
else
    lsb3 = 1;
```

Comment: That gives only the third LSB ?

Comment: No I mean that i need to find the ith LSB each time...I dont need only the 3rd LSB. thanks however

Comment: ah well you never told me that :D